# Why is the default cube pink when the material is set to white?

Tags: materials

As you can see from the screen shot, there are no assigned textures for the currently-selected cube and the color is set to white. The cube in the background is the same except it's got a texture as well. But for both, the color shouldn't be that pink that signifies missing textures.

This is a newly-created scene containing the default cube (the one in the background) and one other added afterwards.
[image: ![Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I had an HDRI set up and it got moved. That was the missing texture.